# why navigation horizontal bar not showing?

Tags: html, css, button, nav

I've having a hard time placing a horizontal divider line between the  tags in the main tier of the navigation, but nothing appears.

I tried doing the first `<ul>` and `<li>`, but a line appears in all the `<li>` child tags under the main `<ul>` I only want the line appear in the main nav, not in the submenus.

I have tried doing the `button.main`, but nothing happens.

What am I doing wrong?

```css
/***** whole navigation bar *****/

nav#prime {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  font-family: "Gill Sans", sans-serif;
  font-size: 14.75px;
}

nav#prime ul {
  /*  whole <ul> tags under <nav> tag */
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

nav#prime li {
  /*selects whole <li> tags under <nav> tag */
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  /*to provide boundry*/
}


/***** links *****/

ul#navbar a:link
/* all normal, unvisitied links under <ul> */

{
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #0E0E10;
  /* jet black */
  color: #FFFAFA;
  /* olde lace white */
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px 11px;
}

ul#navbar a:visited
/* visited link */

{
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
  /* white smoke */
  color: #1A1110;
  /* licorice */
}

ul#navbar a:hover
/* mouse over link, must come after <a:link> and <a:visited> */

{
  background-color: #242124;
  /* raiden */
  color: #FFFFF0;
  /* ivory */
}

ul#navbar a:active
/* a link that's selected - must come after <a:hover> */

{
  background-color: #D3D3D3;
  color: #808080;
}


/***** for all <button> tags *****/

button {
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  font: inherit;
  /* Important for vertical align on mobile phones */
  background-color: #0E0E10;
  /* jet black */
  color: #FFFAFA;
  /* olde lace white */
  margin: 0;
  /* Important for vertical align on mobile phones */
  padding: 5px 11px;
}


/***** submenu positioning *****/

#navbar ul {
  position: absolute;
  white-space: nowrap;
  z-index: 1;
  left: -99999em;
}

#navbar>li:hover>ul {
  position: absolute;
  /*to keep it under relative li*/
  top: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

#navbar>li:hover>li li:hover>ul {
  left: 100%;
}


/***** first tier *****/

#navbar {
  border: 1px solid;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border-color: #0E0E10;
}


/***** first tier *****/

#navbar {
  border: 1px solid;
  border-radius: 4px;
  /*  background-color: #0E0E10;; */
}

.dropbtn-main button #navbar li:not(:first-child):before {
  content: " | ";
  color: green;
}

#navbar>li {
  float: left;
}

li.dropdown button.dropbtn-main
/*
#navigation li:not(:first-child):before {
    
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<nav id="prime">
  <li id="dropdown">
    <ul id="navbar">
      <li class="dropdown">
        <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Ghost
                    <i class="caret-down"></i>
                </button>
        <ul class="submenu">
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li id="dropdown">
    <ul id="navbar">
      <li class="dropdown">
        <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Spirit
                    <i class="caret-down"></i>
                </button>
        <ul class="submenu">
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li id="dropdown">
    <ul id="navbar">
      <li class="dropdown">
        <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Apparition
                    <i class="caret-down"></i>
                </button>
        <ul class="submenu">
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</nav>
```

Comment: ID's must be unique in the document.

Comment: Please look carefully at the structure of your HTML. You cannot have an li element as a direct child of a nav element for example. Put your code through a validator, correct it, ensure the snippet shows as you intend and we can have another look.

Answer (score 0):

you are using a general selection for the hover state add class name to the element you want the specific effect for and try accessing the element in the css with that instead of using attribute selection

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).